# Asymmetric encryption that preserves the plaintext size

Tags: encryption

I'm looking for an asymmetric encryption algorithm that preserves the size of the thong in clear text. The encrypted file must not be longer than the plaintext file and must not contain any special characters.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want these properties?

Comment: Does "thong" mean "string"?

Comment: "must not contain any special characters" -- you use encoding for that.

Comment: Any asymmetric size-preserving encryption is deterministic (by a counting argument) and thus vulnerable to an adversary making a guess of the plaintext. If e.g. you encipher a name on the class roll, that's a disaster. That said, RSA can be made to do what you want, if the plaintext is large enough (about 400 characters depending on character set).

Comment: @schroeder: encoding would increase the size of the ciphertext, which Rig0L said he wants to avoid...

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have any ideas?

Ok, here is a suggestion, however it only works if the messages being encrypted are sufficiently large.

First off; you said that you wanted ciphertexts that "must not contain any special characters"; that would imply that you had a set of $b$ "nonspecial characters", which I assume are the set of valid characters for both the plaintext and the ciphertext.

In addition, the plaintext consists of a string of $n$ of these nonspecial characters, and that the ciphertext must also consist of $n$ nonspecial characters.

Hence, what you want is a trapdoor permutation on a set of $b^n$ values.  I suspect that the underlying cryptoprimitive must also be a trapdoor permutation as well (as the other alternatives I can think of either expand the ciphertext, or run both the encryptor and decryptor in "encryption mode", hence woudln't have the asymmetry you're looking for).

The only true trapdoor permutation I can think of is RSA (I know of a few "trapdoor near permutations", where inverses are not unique but still computable with the private key - those don't work in this situation).

For RSA to be secure, the modulus has to be sufficiently large; at least 2048 bits is considered minimal nowadays; this would imply that $b^n \ge 2^{2048}$, that is, we just wouldn't be able to handle smaller messages.

Now, to select an RSA key, we would select a value $n_{min}$ such that $b^{n_{min}} > 2^{2048}$, with the understanding that we won't be able to encrypt a message that's shorter than $n_{min}$ characters.  Then, we'd select a prime $p \approx \sqrt{b^{n_{min}}}$ and then a prime $q$ with $b^{n_{min}}/p < q < (1 + 2^{-128}) b^{n_{min}}/p $ (there will always be such a prime $q$ available.  This ensures that $pq$ is slightly larger than $b^{n_{min}}$.  Then, we can define a trapdoor permutation of $n_{min}$ characters, by translating the string to an integer from $0$ to $b^{n_{min}}-1$, add 2 to it (on encryption), running the RSA operation on it, if the result happens to be $\ge b^{n_{min}} + 2$, rerunning the RSA operation, and then (after subtracting 2 on encryption) translate the resulting integer back to a string of $n_{min}$ characters.  This gives us a permutation of $n_{min}$ characters that is hard to invert without the private key, but easy to do with it.

We add 2 prior to the RSA operation on encryption and subtract 2 after the RSA operation after decryption to avoid the known fixed points $0, 1, N-1$; by adding 2, we cannot have a plaintext that corresponds to any of these public fixed points.

Now, the question will come up "how do we encrypt messages that happen to be longer than $n_{min}$ characters?  Well, the standard tricks we see in symmetric Format Preserving Encryption don't work (they use Luby-Rackoff constructions, which don't give us the asymmetry we need); the only alternative I can think of is to adapt the overlapping encryption style of [the NIST AES keywrap algorithm](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38F.pdf).  That is, we take the first $n_{min}$ characters, permute those, and then move over $n_{min}/2$ characters, and the encrypt those (and keep on going, wrapping as necessary, until we've made a number of passes through the entire message).  This is inefficient, however it does meet the goal.

Obviously, this is just an outline; however it does indicate that this is possible (for sufficiently long messages).

Comment: What you describe here seems to be a variant of textbook RSA. I think it would make sense to mention that this comes with all of the weaknesses of textbook RSA including that it does not even provide IND-CPA security and is therefore likely not useful in practical applications.

Comment: @dade: actually, depending on the "number of passes" you take through the message (the NIST standard keywrap does 6), it doesn't appear that the standard weaknesses of textbook RSA would apply (except for determinism; that's inherent with the problem).  Now, I don't have a proof of that; however it does appear extremely plausible

Comment: I am not sure I follow the first part of the argument with the key wrap. But without thinking more in depth about it, and without a proof for the contrary I would assume that they apply in some slightly modified form. Generally speaking dererminism is already a strong enough argument against the practical usage of an encryption scheme as it contradicts CPA security and therefore low entropy messages can be easily guessed which is extremely dangerous as less experienced people typically overlook this fact.